# The Monte Carlo of the mean square error of the maximum likelihood estimates

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, monte-carlo, mse

I try to get mean square error of the maximum likelihood estimators in R (using Monte Carlo).

I can write the calculation for the MLE that is repeated once, but I need to repeat the Monte Carlo calculation many times.

Comment: Embed it in a loop where you change the random seed in each iteration to generate a different sample. Store the estimates from each iteration in vectors. Subtract the true values form the vectors. Obtain the MSEs of the resulting vectors.

Comment: Set seed in each iteration of the loop right before generating with `rgumbel`. Then you will have reproducibility. Also remember to take the mean squared *error*, not mean squared *estimate*. I.e. you need to subtract the true value from the estimated one before taking the square and then the mean. Oh... Your true value of $\mu$ is zero, so you are not subtracting it. OK then.

Comment: `set.seed(101)` makes your simulation the same each time. Maybe use `set.seed(i)` or set the seed only once outside the loop and don't reset it inside the loop.

Comment: *"How can we repeat the above process for N=100 times?"* Aren't you doing this already?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, the post has been edited over time. The original version did not contain a loop with 100 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Embed it in a loop where you change the random seed in each iteration to generate a different sample. Store the estimates from each iteration in vectors. Subtract the true values from the vectors. Obtain the MSEs of the resulting vectors.

Comment: @Hermi, you have to vary the seed across the iterations, e.g. `set.seed(100+i)`.

Comment: @Hermi, because then you get exactly the same (even if random) result multiple times. You want random (yet replicable) results, not a the same result over and over again.

Comment: @Hermi, thanks for the bounty!